# Convert chrome extension into cordova mobile app

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js

Is possible to convert a chrome extension into an apache cordova app? I want to reuse my chrome extension vue.js code to create a mobile app and avoid to rewrite all the code but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the code. If you are using a lot of the Chrome APIs that do not have direct support in the Cordova infrastructure, then you may need to rewrite those functionalities. I googled your scenario and the first thing showed up was [this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/chrome_apps_on_mobile). I am not sure if this is relevant but you might want to take a look.

If you can integrate Vue to the Cordova codebase in such a way that you'd done in your Chrome plugin, then I think most of your Vue components can be reused with a very minimum to no modifications. However, from what I understand, codes related to the Chrome extension API will not work for Cordova. You need to redo them in Cordova way. Specially if those involve any system/OS/storage APIs.

Comment: I'm reading the article you've linked but unfortunately chrome apps are deprecated and are available only for chrome OS as I know.  About the codebase, I'm not using all the chrome API but I'm using libraries like dexie.js for storage and axios to get contents using ajax, I need to test if vue can be used inside a cordova app, I don't think that there is a limitation about this implementation